# Аналог PDO::FETCH_COLUMN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Какой есть еще похожий аргумент, только что бы он вернул не одно значение одного столбца, а одно значение двух столбцов, то-есть выполняется запрос:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT s.name1 value, i.name icon FROM prefix_shop s JOIN prefix_images i ON s.id = i.element_id WHERE i.module_name = 'shop' and s.name1 LIKE '%{$keyword}%'");
```

Получаю таблицу из двух столбцов: `value` и `icon` далее в обработчике есть функция:

```
$keyword = $keyword . '%';
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);

    $isQueryOk = $stmt->execute();

    $results = array();


    if ($isQueryOk) {
      $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
    } else {

      trigger_error('Error executing statement.', E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $db = null; 

    return $results;
```

в нем есть строка:

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

меняя `0` на `1` могу выбрать какой столбец выводить, а нужно 2 сразу.

Желательно на выходе по одному запросу получить 2 переменные и записать их, как это можно сделать?

Дам еще другую часть кода, для большего понимания картины:

```
require('database.php');

if (!isset($_GET['keyword'])) {
    die("die");
}

 $keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
 $data = serachForKeyword($keyword);
 echo json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_APOS);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` достанет значения всех колонок запроса (т.е. в Вашем случае оба) и сделает из этого ассоциативный массив, так что Вы сможете обращаться к данным `$result["value"]` и `$result["icon"]`

Ваш запрос вернул Вам несколько строчек. Вам надо через него прокрутиться и из каждой строчки вывести значения.

Примерно так будет выглядеть ваша функция `searchForKeyword()`:

```
function searchForKeyword($keyword) {
    $stmt = $stmt->prepare("SELECT s.name1 value, i.name icon FROM prefix_shop s JOIN prefix_images i ON s.id = i.element_id WHERE i.module_name = 'shop' and s.name1 LIKE '%{$keyword}%'");
    $isQueryOk = $stmt->execute();
    if ($isQueryOk) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "value: " . $row["value"] . " : icon: " . $row["icon"] . "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        trigger_error('Error executing statement.', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Это выведет список того, что вернул запрос.

Только убедитесь, что `$stmt` доступно в функции... через `global` например

Comment: хм, а где теперь подставлять `$result["value"]` и `$result["icon"]` что бы они при запросе выводились?

Comment: немного запутался, что на что нужно заменить?

Comment: обновил, посмотрите